# how to parse a time value of "400" (equivalent to 4:00) using DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, c#-3.0

I'm trying to convert user entered times into TimeSpans.  Because TimeSpan does not have a TryParseExact method I'm using the one in DateTime and converting the output from it.

The formats I want to handle are: 04:00, 0400, 4:00, and 400.  The first three aren't a problem and correspond to the first three cases in the if/else structure in the method below.  The forth could correspond to either of the last two, but neither is working.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime parsedDate = new DateTime();

        string userInput = (string)e.Value;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "HH:mm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "HHmm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;                
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "H:mm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "hmm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, "Hmm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just FYI: Starting in .NET 4 and Silverlight, TimeSpan has a TryParseExact method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact.aspx. Consider retagging with a specific .NET framework version.

Comment: @kbrimington done.  Unfortunately some of the stuff the overarching system needs to integrate doesn't support 4.0 yet.

Comment: That's what I suspected, so I posted only as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply do a `string.PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)` on the user input to ensure the length of the string is 4 characters (minimum). As a result, your Hmm input would then qualify for the HHmm format.

```
userInput = userInput.PadLeft(4, '0'); // "400" becomes "0400"
```

If your string already meets or exceeds 4 in length, it will be left unmodified.

Comment: This could work in part, but would need more code to protect against other problems.  "030" (12:30 am) is valid, "30" is not.

Comment: Yes, in this case, 30 would become 0030. If 2-character inputs are invalid, you would need to enforce that with code when using this method. It would be a trivial check, obviously.

Comment: +1: This is the best workaround.  When the "H" custom format specifier is used, it actually tries to get 2 digits rather than just one, thus invalidating the "mm" specifier (hence the 12:00am syndrome).  The "Hmm" format specifier has been historically problematic and has never worked out of the box.  On the other hand, "HHmm" has always worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

just a general comment- you can have a boolean variable (like isValidDate) initialized to false and set to true where you have

```
 e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
 e.ParsingApplied = true;
```

then move that code to an if block at the end

```
if isValidDate then
        {
            e.Value = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this overload of DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) to specify multiple formats in one go.  It doesn't look like the `Hmm` format will work but you can use integer parsing instead like this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ParseTime("04:00"));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseTime("0400"));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseTime("4:00"));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseTime("400"));
    }

    public static TimeSpan ParseTime(string input)
    {
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        DateTime parsedDateTime;

        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(input, new [] { "HH:mm", "HHmm", "H:mm" }, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime))
        {
            int parsedInt32;

            if (!int.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.None, cultureInfo,  out parsedInt32))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to parse input value as time in any of the accepted formats.", "input");
            }

            int remainder;
            int quotient = Math.DivRem(parsedInt32, 100, out remainder);

            return new TimeSpan(quotient, remainder, 0);
        }

        return parsedDateTime.TimeOfDay;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the overload.  Int parsing was my planned fallback, but I was hoping I'd overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

I used a regex option (I know normally the worse thing to use but the system I was using required it... don't ask):

```
Regex.Replace("935", "^([0-9]{3})$", "0$1"); // outputs "0935"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    userInput,
    new[] { "%H", "Hm", "H:m" },
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out parsedDate);
```

I must give credit for the help I got from: [Why is TryParseExact failing on Hmm and Hmmss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss)