# Cannot parse custom date string using ParseExact

Tags: c#, date-parsing

I faced with issue related to `DateTime.ParseExact`. Cannot parse string with 1 digit for month.

```
//this works fine with 2 digits for month
DateTime.TryParseExact("030405", "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

//this works also fine with 1 digit for month but with hyphen or space
DateTime.TryParseExact("3-04-05", "M-dd-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
DateTime.TryParseExact("3 04 05", "M dd yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

//but this DOES NOT work with 1 digit without hyphen
DateTime.TryParseExact("30405", "Mddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

For me it looks illogically.

Comment: Why can't you add s leading zero by doing PadLeft(6, "0") ?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni Sure I can, and I've already done this for my purpose. But I'm just curious why it doesn't work.

Comment: It's very very strange. I would post it as an open issue in the .NET framework. I Guess you need to look at the function's implementation to realy understand why you get this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss

Comment: From the OP's answer to that question is appears that even though you've specified that you want a single digit month it grabs two digits to try to parse which then doesn't leave enough data for other format specifiers.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks. I just thought about it and such logic, and it seems to be very logically. It works like that for `ToString(format)` and it should works for parsing in the same way.