# ParseExact/TryParseExact failing with single digit hour

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a time and a date value with no field delimiters which I'm attempting to parse into a `DateTime` using `TryParseExact`. The time component has a single digit hour, and two digit minutes and seconds.

The following expression:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20170101 84457", "yyyyMMdd Hmmss", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

results in `FormatException` with the message "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". I am assuming that this is because the time can't be unambiguously resolved, however since `mm` and `ss` are always going to be two digits each, I don't understand why this would be an issue.

The following results in successful parsing:

- Hacking the input time to include delimiters (e.g., '8:44:57' and 'H:mm:ss')
- Kludging the input time to have a leading zero if < 6 digits

Both of these seem a bit of a hack.

Comment: It might be a hack, but forcing a 0 prefix may just be what you have to do.

Comment: It appears that the cause is due to how ParseExact works under the hood, attempting to greedily retrieve two characters when it can. There's a breakdown of the behaviour here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss/2016451#2016451

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem. `DateTime.ParseExact` ends up calling `DateTimeParse.DoStrictParse`, and even though you specify `H`, it still grabs two digits to evaluate for the hour. The source code is here if you really want to see how it works: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/f1835935628e4a2f.html

Comment: Format H means value can be between 0 to 23. It is obvious that even though format has been specified as H still value can be of 2 digit. Perhaps that;s the reason why to read 2 digit to form H.

Comment: @nullPainter You can see what .NET Team suggest for this situation on my answer as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778076/447156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand from [other people's research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss/2016451#2016451), parsing attempts to retrieve two digits if it can, and parses from left to right.

Using my failing example of the raw time value `84857` and format `Hmmss`, because the hour is followed by a digit, it will be parsed as `84` - hence throwing a format exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or time separators (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, **specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H"**.

So it appears that if you don't have any delimiters, you are required to use `HH` and not `H`.

Personally I would pad the time component to 6 digits and use HH. The following works fine for me:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20170101 084457", "yyyyMMdd hhmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to wrap this in a custom function, you can use something like this:

```
    static DateTime ParseDateTime(string input)
    {
        int dateInteger, timeInteger;

        var s = input.Split(' ');
        bool dateOK = int.TryParse(s[0], out dateInteger);
        bool timeOK = int.TryParse(s[1], out timeInteger);

        if (!dateOK || !timeOK) throw new FormatException("Invalid date/time string.");

        var newInput = String.Format("{0:00000000} {1:000000}", dateInteger, timeInteger);
        return DateTime.ParseExact(newInput, "yyyyMMdd hhmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: I read and attempted that too. Unfortunately that manifests the same behaviour.

Comment: Works fine for me. You sure you got it right?

Comment: My response was to your answer before you edited it to add a leading zero to the time. I am also currently adding a leading zero, but it seems a bit of a kludge.

Comment: Using just `H` works fine if the input is padded with a leading `0` (also in your example you are switching to a 12-hour clock instead of the expected 24-hour clock)

Comment: I didn't edit my answer to add a digit... I cut and pasted working code from my Visual Studio. Maybe you were looking at a different answer.  FWIW, storing a time as a 5-digit integer also seems like a kludge, no offense.

Comment: Oh, I agree. In this case, the time is an integer being returned from a mainframe.

Comment: You added the note "...I would pad the time component to 6 digits...". `DateTime.ParseExact("20170101 84457", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` fails, as I noted.

Comment: For me it worked after changing 8 to 08.