# date format not parsing as expected with try parse exact function

Tags: c#, .net, date, formatting

the code:

```
DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3).AddMinutes(-33).AddMonths(3).AddDays(21).ToString("ddMMMy Hmm")
```

gives the result:

```
 28May19 901
```

Hovever when I pass this date into the TryParseExact method I get the following :

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("28May19 901", "ddMMMyy Hmm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
false
```

How could this be false? and what would the correct format be?

**EDIT:**

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture does not make a difference:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("28May19 901", "ddMMMyy Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt); false
```

Comment: Depends on your current culture. For me it would also be false because my May is Mai. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` (**Edit** but it's still false for me)

Comment: @Rango still false and not working

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact("28May19 901", "ddMMMyy Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
false`

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact("28May19 9:01", "ddMMMyy H:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt); true

Comment: @Gowtham Alan the string is being parsed in without the colon separator

Comment: @Gowtham Alan is there a way without using the colon seperator?

Comment: This is the correct duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss (someone close please). Without a leading zero your hours are read as `90` which is of course no correct hour.

Comment: as @Rango said, this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016206/net-why-is-tryparseexact-failing-on-hmm-and-hmmss

Comment: should I delete the question?